# Expect gets stuck sometimes during login

Tags: authentication, expect

I have the following script. Sometimes, it runs fine and others it gets stuck.  What could be wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
# set Variables
set timeout 60
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 0]
# start telnet connection 
spawn telnet $ipaddr
match_max 100000
# Look for user prompt 
expect "username:*"
send -- "admin\r"
expect "password:?"
# Send pass
send "thisisthepass\n"
# look for WWP prompt
expect ">" 
send "sendthiscommand\r"
expect ">"
send "exit\r"
interact
```

The script runs fine till the end, but sometimes it gets stuck during login. This behavior is present even with the same IP: for example, it may run 1 out of 5 tries for the same IP.

I have tried adding some sleep between sending of the user and password, but it's still the same. I have also tried without expect, by sending directly the password string after the user one but still the same: sometimes the script runs fine but others it asks again for the password as if it's incorrect...

```
username: admin
password:

username:
```

Answer (score 1):

Things I would do:

- change `send "thisisthepass\n"` to `send "thisisthepass\r"`
- include `exp_internal 1` somewhere at the top of your script, and see what is going on when you have a failed attempt

`exp_internal 1` will enable debugging with lots of good information on what is going on with expect's pattern matching. You can share it here and I'll be glad to take a look at it.

Are you sure the password prompt has an extra character after it (your `?` in `expect "password:?"`. Is it always there? Any chance different devices have slightly different password prompts?